# Highlight table elements with selection box - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to color all elements that share the same 3 data values as the selected element by using a selection box. It only works with the first selection but not on concurrent ones. In my for loop the console does not show what I expect it to do? I must be missing something that is accustomed to Jquery itself.

Here is the JS:

```
function setColor(){
        $('input').on('click', function(){
        var src, // packet source
            dst,
            proto;// 

        var $selectedRow = $("tr[class='selectedrow']"); // get selected row

            color = $(this).val(); // grab selected color from radio button
            console.log(color);


        $tdelements = $selectedRow.children();  //get td elements of selected row
        src = $tdelements.eq(2).text(); // grab source 
        dst = $tdelements.eq(3).text(); // grab destination
        proto = $tdelements.eq(4).text(); // grab protocol

            var $tr = $('tr'); // grab entire <tr> of document.

            console.log($tr.eq(0).children());

            // loop through individual <tr> elements and compare fields with the filter.
            for(var i=0; i < $tr.length; i++){
               $tdelements =  $tr.eq(i).children(); // grab elements of the ith tr element
                console.log($tdelements.eq(i));
               if($tdelements.eq(2).text() === src && $tdelements.eq(3).text() === dst && $tdelements.eq(4).text() === proto){
                   $tr.eq(i).removeClass(color);
                   $tr.eq(i).addClass(color);
               }
            }
        }); 

}




// Dom Ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
        $('tr').removeClass('selectedrow');
        $(this).addClass('selectedrow') ;
    });
    setColor();
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/senpaifiddler/ztd1Ltux/

Comment: I suppose that first you need to remove "color" class properly. Look at https://jsfiddle.net/sL0uLuvb/ . And 2nd is - you define var `color` as value of radio button, then you do this: `$tr.eq(i).removeClass(color);` but this `tr` may have another color that differs from choosen buttons color.

Comment: I do not want the color to be removed when the user clicks on the table. I want the current color to change when I select a different color from the radio box. That is essentially the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected row using `var $selectedRow = $("tr.selectedrow")`.

You need to remove previously applied classes using

```
$tr.removeClass('red')
  .removeClass('green')
  .removeClass('blue')
  .removeClass('yellow');
```

And, we don't need `removeClass` before adding a the same class on any element. That's why I have updated

```
$tr.eq(i).removeClass(color);
$tr.eq(i).addClass(color);
```

to

```
$(this).addClass(color);
```

where `this` is your current element in the `$.each` loop.

Also, I have modified the code to iterate `<tr>`s using [`$.each`.](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Also, I have added `<label>` for the radio's for simplifying the selection.

**Update**: Issues your code

1. `$("tr[class='selectedrow']")`: It selects elements having only 'selectedrow' class which works fine in first run. Afterwards, when you add a new class, lets say 'red', your `selectedrow` class now becomes `selectedrow red`. It can be retrieved by `$("tr[class='selectedrow red']")`.
2. `$tr.eq(i).removeClass(color);
    $tr.eq(i).addClass(color);`
   In first run, lets suppose, you have selected 'red' color, it will add class 'red'. Afterwards, you have selected 'green', what it wil do, it will remove 'green' class from `$(tr).eq(i)` and then add 'green' class. But, your `selectedrow` contains the 'red' class. How will it remove previously selected color('red')?

Try this snippet.

```js
console.clear();

function setColor() {
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    var src, // packet source
      dst,
      proto; // 

    var $selectedRow = $("tr.selectedrow"); // get selected row

    color = $(this).val(); // grab selected color from radio button


    $tdelements = $selectedRow.children(); //get td elements of selected row
    src = $tdelements.eq(2).text(); // grab source 
    dst = $tdelements.eq(3).text(); // grab destination
    proto = $tdelements.eq(4).text(); // grab protocol

    var $tr = $('tr'); // grab entire <tr> of document.

    $tr.removeClass('red')
      .removeClass('green')
      .removeClass('blue')
      .removeClass('yellow');

    // loop through individual <tr> elements and compare fields with the filter.
    $tr.each(function() {
      $tdelements = $(this).children(); // grab elements of the ith tr element
      if ($tdelements.eq(2).text() === src && $tdelements.eq(3).text() === dst && $tdelements.eq(4).text() === proto) {
        $(this).addClass(color);
      }
    });

  });

}

// Dom Ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $('tr').removeClass('selectedrow');
    $(this).addClass('selectedrow');
  });
  setColor();
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.container {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.selectedrow {
  color: aqua;
  background: white;
}
.red {
  color: red;
  background: white;
}
.green {
  color: green;
  background: white;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
  background: white;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
  background: white;
}
label {
  display: inline-block!important;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="JQuery: Highlight table elements with selection box">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>src</td>
            <td>dst</td>
            <td>protocol</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>src</td>
            <td>dst</td>
            <td>protocol</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>src</td>
            <td>dst</td>
            <td>protocol</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>src</td>
            <td>dst</td>
            <td>protocol</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>src</td>
            <td>dst</td>
            <td>protocol</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>src</td>
            <td>dst</td>
            <td>protocol</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>src</td>
            <td>dst</td>
            <td>protocol</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="radRed" value="red">
        <label for="radRed">Red</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="radBlue" value="blue">
        <label for="radBlue">Blue</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="radGreen" value="green">
        <label for="radGreen">Green</label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="radYellow" value="yellow">
        <label for="radYellow">Yellow</label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The reason why this fixes the problem is because, when the user selects a different color the variables are all empty and causes the if-statement not to execute at all. I do not know if this should be selected as the correct answer since it does not identify the bug ? Unless, an explanation is provided as to why the variables become empty and why you should use this method instead.

Comment: @IskandarG Updated the answer with issue. Let me know if you would have any more questions.

Comment: this is good enough, wonder if this will work if the rows of the table are dynamically extended ? Will test it and update it as necessary. Also, I personally do not like using $.each() since it is slower and what is wrong with the regular old for loop?

Comment: I used `$.each` because your most of the code is in JQuery. Otherwise, even I personally would have used `for`. And, `$.addClass` wouldn't be faster than `classList.add`. But it was there in your code. Btw, its your call. Hope it helps. peace. :)

Comment: Lol! thanks and fair enough, I just use JQuery's DOM manipulation because of it's cross-platform capabilities. Pure javaScript is much more powerful when it comes to very specific tasks.